# Getting Factor Means into the dataset after calculation

Tags: r, normalization, mean, r-factor

I am trying to create a normalization value for a variable I am working with based on individual conference means and SDs. I found the conference means using the function:

`confavg=aggregate(base$AVG, by=list(base$confName), FUN=mean)`

And so after getting the means for the 31 conferences, I want to go back and for each individual player put these means in so I can easily calculate a normalization factor based on the conference mean.

I have tried to create large ifelse or if statements where confavg is the conference average.

`ifelse((base$confName=="America East Conference"),confavg[1,2]->base$CAVG,0->base$CAVG)`

but nothing works. Ideally I would want to take every player and say:

`Normalization = (player average - conference average)/conference standard deviation`

How should I go about doing that?

edit:

Here is some sample data:

```
AVG = c(.350,.400,.320,.220,.100,.250,.400,.450)
Conf = c("SEC","ACC","SEC","B12","P12","ACC","B12","P12")
Conf=as.factor(Conf)
sampleconfavg=aggregate(AVG, by=list(Conf), FUN=mean)
sampleconfsd=aggregate(AVG, by=list(Conf), FUN=sd)
```

So each player would have their average - the conference average / sd of conference

so for the first guy it would be:

```
(.350 - .335) / 0.0212132 = 0.7071069
```

but I am hoping to build a function that does it for all people in my dataset. Thank you!

edit2:

Alright the answer below is amazing but I am running into (hopefully) one last problem. I want to basically do this process to three variables like:

```
base3=do.call(rbind, by(base3, base3$confName, FUN=function(x) { x$ScaledAVG <- scale(x$AVG); x}))
base3=do.call(rbind, by(base3, base3$confName, FUN=function(x) { x$ScaledOBP <- scale(x$OBP); x}))
base3=do.call(rbind, by(base3, base3$confName, FUN=function(x) { x$ScaledK.AB <- scale(x$K.AB); x}))
```

Which works but then when I search the datafile like:

```
base3[((base3$ScaledAVG>2)&(base3$ScaledOBP>2)&(base3$ScaledK.AB<.20)),]
```

it resets the Scaled K.AB value and doesn't use it as part of the parameters of the search.

Comment: It helps a lot to post sample data.

Comment: Good idea, I added some sample code!

Comment: You're going to have to demonstrate what you mean by the last edit.  It would probably be better to put that as another question.

Comment: Alright I will post it as another question, you have been an incredible help.

Comment: I have posted it here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593537/using-do-call-factor-to-scale-resetting-value-error

Comment: If I have answered *this* question, you should check the mark (again).  It is good form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to scale iris$Sepal.Length, within groups of iris$Species:

```
scaled.iris <- do.call(rbind, 
  by(iris, iris$Species,
     FUN=function(x) { x$Scaled.Sepal.Length <- scale(x$Sepal.Length); x }
  )
)

head(scaled.iris)
##          Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Scaled.Sepal.Length
## setosa.1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa          0.26667447
## setosa.2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa         -0.30071802
## setosa.3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa         -0.86811050
## setosa.4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa         -1.15180675
## setosa.5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa         -0.01702177
## setosa.6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa          1.11776320
```

Edit:

Using your sample data (`Conf` and `AVG` only):

```
d <- data.frame(Conf, AVG)
dd <- do.call(rbind, by(d, d$Conf, FUN=function(x) { x$Scaled <- scale(x$AVG); x}))

# Remove generated row names
rownames(dd) <- NULL

dd
##   Conf  AVG     Scaled
## 1  ACC 0.40  0.7071068
## 2  ACC 0.25 -0.7071068
## 3  B12 0.22 -0.7071068
## 4  B12 0.40  0.7071068
## 5  P12 0.10 -0.7071068
## 6  P12 0.45  0.7071068
## 7  SEC 0.35  0.7071068
## 8  SEC 0.32 -0.7071068
```

Comment: hmmm, I like the idea but I can't get it to work for me. I am using the code like this where CAVG is the variable I am hoping it ends up in, and confName is the conference name factor and AVG is the starting average, while base is the dataset.

Comment: scaled.avg <- do.call(rbind, 
  by(base, base$confName,
     FUN=function(x) { base$CAVG <- scale(base$AVG); x }
  )
)

Comment: That is awesome. I am almost there, how do I attach it to the original dataset in the right columns? When I am doing the large one, it organizes by last name rather than the conference organization it outputs through this so I can't just do a [,7] apply.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand.  It seems that I am adding the column to the data frame.

Comment: You're right, I just have to resave it as a frame, I was just running the code and it would spit it out right but I wasn't saving it outside of the output window. Thanks!

Comment: One more question. When I run that code it renames each row every time. It isn't a big deal but it is getting slightly unruly when I run it around 4 times for various statistics and get row things of:
Atlantic Coast Conference.Atlantic Coast Conference.Atlantic Coast Conference.1 for each one. Any ideas to shorten it?

Comment: Thank you, I made another edit to the problem. I am having things reset and it now allowing me to use it as an operator to search on.