# Using do.call factor to scale - resetting value error

Tags: r, search, normalization, r-factor, do.call

This is an extension of the question that I asked here: 
[Getting Factor Means into the dataset after calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591704/getting-factor-means-into-the-dataset-after-calculation)

Now that I have basically normalized all of the stats that I am interested in using 
I want to search the data set for people that intersect with these. Thus I am searching the dataset like this:

```
base3[((base3$ScaledAVG>2)&(base3$ScaledOBP>2)&(base3$ScaledK.AB<.20)),]
```

looking for the players that have all three of those things true, yet when I run this it resets the Scaled K.AB value to either .5, 1 or 2 and then doesn't search using that parameter. Is there something wrong with searching the data set this way or is there a better way to find people in a dataset in this same vein?

Here is some sample data but it doesn't have the same problems as when I go out to the 4000 records I have:

```
AVG = c(.350,.400,.320,.220,.100,.250,.400,.450)
Conf = c("SEC","ACC","SEC","B12","P12","ACC","B12","P12")
OBP = c(.360,.420,.360,.260,.160,.260,.460,.410)
K.AB = c(.11,.10,.09,.25,.20,.19,.05,.09)
Conf=as.factor(Conf)
d<- data.frame(Conf, AVG,OBP,K.AB)
dd <- do.call(rbind, by(d, d$Conf, FUN=function(x) { x$Scaled <- scale(x$AVG); x}))
dd <- do.call(rbind, by(d, d$Conf, FUN=function(x) { x$Scaled <- scale(x$OBP); x}))
dd <- do.call(rbind, by(d, d$Conf, FUN=function(x) { x$Scaled <- scale(x$K.AB); x}))
dd[((dd$ScaledAVG>2)&(dd$ScaledOBP>2)&(dd$ScaledK.AB<.20)),]
```

Thank you!

Comment: The sample data you provide is nigh on useless - what is `base3`? You have `confName` and `Conf`, and no `Scaled` anything. Please make this reproducible.

Comment: The final function won't do anything on this data but hypothetically if you had a bunch and had values that were 2 sds above the mean for these is this the best way to get at them or are there better ways of doing this?

Comment: And I rewrote the sample data, I apologize for not making it reproducable! This should all work except for the final part.

Comment: You are overwriting the values of `dd`. Only the last assignment will survive.

Comment: How should I got about doing all three together so they stick?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to drop the do.call(rbind, by(...)) strategy in favor of a straight `scale` strategy. The `scale function has a`data.frame` method.

```
> dd <- scale(d[ ,c("AVG", "OBP", "K.AB")])
> dd
             AVG        OBP       K.AB
[1,]  0.33566727  0.2348519 -0.3608439
[2,]  0.76878633  0.8281619 -0.5051815
[3,]  0.07579584  0.2348519 -0.6495191
[4,] -0.79044229 -0.7539981  1.6598820
[5,] -1.82992803 -1.7428481  0.9381942
[6,] -0.53057085 -0.7539981  0.7938566
[7,]  0.76878633  1.2237019 -1.2268693
[8,]  1.20190539  0.7292769 -0.6495191
attr(,"scaled:center")
    AVG     OBP    K.AB 
0.31125 0.33625 0.13500 
attr(,"scaled:scale")
       AVG        OBP       K.AB 
0.11544170 0.10112757 0.06928203 

> d[ dd[, 'AVG'] > 2 & dd[ ,'OBP'] >2 & dd[ ,'K.AB'] < 0.2 , ]
[1] Conf AVG  OBP  K.AB
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

It should not be too surprising that you get no rows that meet all of those conditions since a scaled value of 2 is rather unlikely in a small dataset.

To apply scale within levels of Conf:

```
> dd <- lapply(d[ ,c("AVG", "OBP", "K.AB")], function(x) ave(x, d[,"Conf"] , FUN=scale) )
> dd
$AVG
[1]  0.7071068  0.7071068 -0.7071068 -0.7071068 -0.7071068 -0.7071068  0.7071068  0.7071068

$OBP
[1]        NaN  0.7071068        NaN -0.7071068 -0.7071068 -0.7071068  0.7071068  0.7071068

$K.AB
[1]  0.7071068 -0.7071068 -0.7071068  0.7071068  0.7071068  0.7071068 -0.7071068 -0.7071068

> data.frame(dd)
         AVG        OBP       K.AB
1  0.7071068        NaN  0.7071068
2  0.7071068  0.7071068 -0.7071068
3 -0.7071068        NaN -0.7071068
4 -0.7071068 -0.7071068  0.7071068
5 -0.7071068 -0.7071068  0.7071068
6 -0.7071068 -0.7071068  0.7071068
7  0.7071068  0.7071068 -0.7071068
8  0.7071068  0.7071068 -0.7071068
```

I do not think it works too well here because the offered test case is too small.

Comment: That works for what I said in this problem however the main thing we are working towards is that we are scaling towards conference means rather than the overall mean. We are trying to normalize certain statistics by which league they play in. Is there a way to edit your code to go towards a conference scaling? (Conference is the factor variable Conf.

Comment: Is there a way to write these to the existing dataset? I have tried cbinding them together as cbind(d,dd) basically but this doesn't let me search then. Is there a way to compute it using the lapply function and then attach them to the dataset in the correct rows? Like for each individual statistic we will still be able to see who has the higher average or OBP etc but won't be able to compare their scaled values without those values connected.

Comment: I do not understand why cbind(d,dd)-ing "doesn't let you search". Neither `ave` nor `scale` will reorder the rows.